# Angular / Firebase - Extracting date and time from timestamp

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material

I have an angular form where there’s a date input (using Angular materials date picker) and a time picker (using https://github.com/IliaIdakiev/angular-material-timepicker). When i create a new item, the date is pre-populated with a Firestore timestamp. In my edit form, both the date and time are referencing the same field. Both seem to be read correctly.

If i change the time, the time aspect of the field is updated and the date is left alone. That’s good. However, whenever I change the date, it overwrites the date AND time aspects. Looking at my save button for the form (which will update the date) I have the following:

```
let formValue = { ...this.form.value };
for (let prop in formValue) {
  if (!formValue[prop] && formValue[prop] != 0) {
    delete formValue[prop];
  }
}

this.doc.update(formValue)
```

**What i'd like to achieve**

1. When updating the time from the `angular-material-timepicker`, it updates only the time for the existing timestamp (this currently works!)
2. When updating the date from the `Angular Material Date Picker`, that it only updates the date, not the time. (Right now, changing the date will reset the value to something like `January 20, 2021 at 12:00:00 AM UTC`)